# Resetar AUTO INCREMENT e organizar ID dos itens

Tags: mysql, sql

Que comando posso utilizar para reorganizar a ID de todos os itens de uma tabela?

O nome da tabela é `produtos` e da coluna é `id`.

Atualmente eles estão dessa forma:

**id:** 1 - 3 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 11...

Ou seja, não estão em sequência correta.

Eu preciso deixar eles dessa forma:

**id**: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7...

Porém é importante que ele siga a sequência correta para não misturar, ex:

> 1 = 1
> 3 = 2 
> 7 = 3
>  8 = 4
>  9 = 5
>  11 = 6

O servidor é MySQL.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam `MySQL` é um servidor de banco de dados.

Comment: @Wendler se não me engano, isso só será possível se você `truncar` a tabela, mas quando você realizar uma exclusão, o `MySQL` não irá reordenar, até porque o `id` não pode ser alterado já que pode estar referenciado em outras tabelas.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos...Pois é, teria que ser através de um `UPDATE` seguindo algumas condições, ou será que não é possível dessa forma?

Comment: @Sveen... Excelente amigo, não tinha visto essa pergunta ai, realmente resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Eu também tinha pesquisado isso esses dias hahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para regularizar sua base, você precisa atualizar os dados já cadastrados, como bem sugeriu [@sveen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/39717/sveen).

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `tabela` SET `tabela`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Feito isso, você precisa atualizar seu "*contador*" para que os novos itens inseridos sigam à partir do último *index*.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tabela) + 1
```

Detalhe: se existe a possibilidade de deleção física (apagar os registros da base), sugiro você não usar o `auto_increment`, e sim uma coluna numérica que pode ser controlada mais facilmente via código.