# Utilizar ids em falta

Tags: mysql

Após ver esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292738/resetar-auto-increment-e-organizar-id-dos-itens) lembrei-me de um problema do qual já me deparei diversas vezes:

Vamos supor que existe a seguinte tabela:

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça
2 | Banana
3 | Pêra
```

Caso elimine `Banana` e adicione `Pêssego` e `Abacaxi`ficarei com:

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça  
3 | Pêra  
4 | Pêssego  
5 | Abacaxi
```

Mas o que pretendo é:

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça
2 | Pêssego
3 | Pêra
4 | Abacaxi
```

Ou seja quero sempre aproveitar os id com o numero de sequencia em falta, caso não haja nenhum então é apenas sequêncial (+1).

Previamente havia resolvido esta situação fazendo um pedido á base de dados e verificando os numeros em falta atavés de PHP. Mas penso que não é muito performático, também poderia tentar limitar o resultado e fazer vários pedidos, mas também não ajuda.

Em termos de performance existe algum método em sql para resolver este problema? Ou até algum algorítmo padrão (em qualquer linguagem, PHP foi um exemplo) para avaliar estas situações?

---

O seguinte código não responde á pergunta:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `tabela` SET `tabela`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Pois irá ordernar tudo, estrangando a seguencia das frutas anteriores.

Vamos supor:

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça
4 | Abacaxi
```

Insiro um registo novo e executo a query anterior, ficará

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça
2 | Abacaxi
3 | Maça
```

Mas o pretendido é:

```
Fruta
-----------
1 | Maça
2 | Maça
4 | Abacaxi
```

Ou seja, não queremos perder a ligação ao numero já associado as frutas existentes.

Comment: Isto é por curiosidade ou você deseja mesmo fazer isto?

Comment: Já resolvi esta questão em um projecto utilizando php para apurar os numeros em falta, mas gostaria de saber se existe algum método em mysql, ou alguma algoritmo padrão. Ou seja curiosidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como organizar a numeração auto-incremento de uma coluna Id de uma tabela no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/601/como-organizar-a-numera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-auto-incremento-de-uma-coluna-id-de-uma-tabela-no-mys)

Comment: Pergunta duplicada, você pode ver uma solução [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/601/como-organizar-a-numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-auto-incremento-de-uma-coluna-id-de-uma-tabela-no-mys)

Comment: Não responde á pergunta porque vai ordenar tudo, e irá estragar a sequencia de outros numeros ja atribuidos. Supondo 1,4, insiro uma novo registo e ficará 1,2,3 e não é isso o pretendido mas sim 1,2,4

Comment: O autoincrement é sempre incremental, só adiciona depois da último id inserido (contador). O que você está querendo é uma estrutura de dados chamada de "lista ordenada estática", Você pode implementar isso sem usar o autoincrement, mas não vejo a necessidade de uma situação onde seria viável fazer isso.

Comment: Nunca falei em autoincrement. Mas sim em sequencia, apesar do campo ser numérico nunca mencionei que seria autoincrement.

Comment: Mas a idéia de um campo ID deve ser um auto-incremental, pois não existe outra solução-algoritmo, nativa em mysql, para gerar automaticamente o campo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se quer performance, um jeito bem simples de achar números livres é este:

```
SELECT
  a.num - 1 AS livre
FROM
  frutas AS a
  LEFT JOIN frutas AS b ON a.num - 1 = b.num
WHERE
  b.num IS NULL AND a.num > 1
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b397a3/2)**.

O que fizemos aqui basicamente foi um `LEFT JOIN` da tabela com ela própria, relacionando o `num` de um lado com o `num - 1` do outro, e pegando apenas os sem correspondência (ou seja, somente os com intervalo).

Estou chamando de números, pois se você reaproveita, não convém mais chamar de "id", pois o número passa a não identificar unicamente cada elemento.

A "limitação" desta *query* é que ela depende de já existir algum número na base de dados para detectar os "anteriores" livres, mas isto não é um problema, visto que se vai reaproveitar, a ordem das vagas reusadas não deve ser tão importante, desde que mantenha as usadas (e eventualmente você ao ocupar as vagas, vai acabar chegando ao número 1 de qualquer forma);

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado @Bacco. É "simples" e funciona em pleno.